# 80's Animation Sci-Fi Movie - Woman and man on a planet attacked by large colorful bees

Tags: movie, animation, story-identification

First of all, the movie is not Nausicäa or Time Masters (1982). Although it is kinda similar.

What I remember (memory is 17 years old):

I saw this movie on Free-TV or VHS in maybe 2002. The animation style I have in memory is Anime, realistic, kind of like in "Time Masters" but more colorful and it looked more modern.

There's a group of people on a planet. They are searching for something. On the planet are different plants and insects. While the group is wandering the planet they are being attacked by the insects. I remember bee-like insects. Very big bees kinda. But bigger and more colorful like in Time Masters. Also after this happens there is a man and a woman in a swimming pool taking a bath together. (Yes, this sounds just like Time Masters but it isn't!). The pool is modern looking and under water they are kissing.

Comment: Are you sure it's not Time Masters?

Comment: Pretty sure, yes.

Comment: There's also a young boy in the group while they are being attacked. Maybe several kids.

Comment: For some reason this made me think of the Heavy Metal film from 1981.

Comment: It's not Heavy Metal, too.